# Declare mutliple variables in for loop

Tags: javascript

I am trying to declare multiple variables in a for loop but the way I am doing it its not working,
I tried to search for similar questions but couldnt find...

```
 for (var n = 0;  n < 10; n++) 
   {  
        var b + n = document.getElementById("b" + n);               
   }
```

Comment: So you want to end up with variables named `b0`, `b1`, `b2`, ... `b9`?

Comment: Just use an array

Comment: Can't do that. Every loop you overwrite your "var" with the var declaration.

Comment: Variable names should be statically defined.

Comment: You can't do like 'var b + n' instead, you can try ' b[n]'. You can't make a variable name with + operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the **Array**

```
var b = new Array();
for (var n = 0;  n < 10; n++) 
{  
    b[n] = document.getElementById("b" + n);               
}
```

Comment: Duplicate answer to duplicate question.